# PayPal Buttons in Flutter Web with a Node SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-buttons

I am looking for a way to add PayPal buttons in Flutter Web. Since I am not very smart I only could add those from html code, but it is only redirection.

I need to use JavaScript PayPal buttons or gateway (I tried to integrate from one tutorial with this: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK
but got the error 'invalid payerID'

Answer (score 1):

> https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK

That SDK is deprecated and uses the deprecated v1/payments API.

If you need a server SDK for checkout, use [Checkout-NodeJS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK)

You'll need two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return JSON, and the latter should check the response from PayPal and do any important success/failure operations that need to happen server-side.

The approval flow to pair with the two routes is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server